# Javascript - How to listen for changes in Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firebase cloud Firestore for my Project. I want to listen for changes in a list inside the users' document and when an item gets added to the list I want to run a function.

So how to listen to the changes in a list in every single user document at the same time?

My Database has the following structure:
[image]

Comment: Do you need to get the changes in each and every document? Or just of the user who is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Firestore API to listen to changes in a specific list of a specific document.  There is only an API to listen to **any** changes in a specific document.  That API is discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes).  If you want to know if a list changed within that document, you will have to compare snapshots of that document over time to figure out if something changed.

See also:

- [Flutter Firestore How To Listen For Changes To ONE Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982928/flutter-firestore-how-to-listen-for-changes-to-one-document)
- [The formal FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes)